# What is the use of hidden_field method on Page 491 in Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

(First of all, I want to note that this question might only be answered if you have read the book or even got the book in your hand so that you can read the relevant part on Page 491, since I can only extract a small section and paste it here. I apologize for that.)

This is the _follow.html.erb partial used in the book on page **491**:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.
                          build(:followed_id => @user.id) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div> 
<% end %>
```

It is for creating a "follow" button to follow other users.

And then in his explanation of the line dealt with the "f.hidden_field", he said,

> Finally, you’ll note that the form doesn’t have any content other than the button, but it still needs to send the followed_id, which we accomplish with hidden_field;

My questions are:

Why do we need a hidden_field here to send the followed_id? As far as I see it, the line

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.
                      build(:followed_id => @user.id) do |f| %>
```

has already assigned the :followed_id attribute right?

Answer (score 1):

I think those two part of code are different.

```rb
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @user.id) do |f| %>
```

This line creates a new record for the form.

```rb
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
```

This code create an actual params of your form.

--> You might want to read that to learn more about form_for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: I don't want to be rude on this, but could you please reframe your English a bit so that I can understand you more clearly? thanks, damienbrz.

Comment: To try and make it a bit more clear. The first line builds a temporary object for the form_for method to use while creating the form. In this case a relationship.
The second line builds the hidden field with the data from the temporary object he just built.